# Redmine 2.3.2 Email configuration for Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, redmine

We have recently run `Redmine 2.3.2`from the downloaded Virtual Machine and set up some initial settings.  I need to set up the email configuration for gmail.  i edited the file `configuration.yml` found in `opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/config` to the following:

```
production:
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :smtp
smtp_settings:
tls: true
address: "smtp.gmail.com" 
port: 587
domain: "smtp.gmail.com" 
authentication: :plain
user_name: "user@gmail.com" 
password: "password" 
enable_starttls_auto: true
```

I am still getting the following error when i try to browse `localhost/redmine`

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

Any ideas?

Hi and thanks for your reply. There seems to be some progress made now :)The error now is different: An error occurred while sending mail (Connection refused - connect(2)). 
the following is the configuration.yml, i added the number of spaces (sp) in brackets just to confirm

```
production: (no sp) 
  email_delivery: (2 sp at beginning) 
    delivery_method: :smtp (4 sp at beginning, 1 sp between the colons) 
    smtp_settings: (4 sp) 
      enable_startttls_auto: true (6 sp,1 sp after colon) 
      address: "smtp.gmail.com" (6 sp,1 sp after colon) 
      port: '587' (6 sp,1 sp after colon,single inverted commas) 
      domain: "smtp.gmail.com" (6 sp, 1 sp after colon) 
      authentication: plain (6 sp, 1 sp after colon) 
      user_name: "username@gmail.com" (6 sp,1 sp after colon) 
      password: "1234" (6 sp, 1 sp after colon)
```

I also eliminated the single inverted commas and inverted commas with no success.  Any ideas of what can be wrong ? Are there any log files which can give more information on whats going on at the background?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

- did you restart redmine after the changes?
- is your indentation correct? in the paste above it is not, but stackoverflow might have broken it...
- the official suggestion is slightly different from what you have, see http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration#Simple-Login-Authentication-default-settings and check the `enable_starttls_auto: true` part

it should look something like this

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp.gmail.com" 
      port: '587'
      domain: "smtp.gmail.com" 
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: "your_email@gmail.com" 
      password: "your_password"
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply.  There seems to be some progress made now :)The error now is different This is how the file looks now with spaces

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply.  There seems to be some progress made now :)The error now is different: An error occurred while sending mail (Connection refused - connect(2)). the following is the configuration.yml, i added the number of spaces (sp) in brackets just to confirm

Comment: production: (no sp)
  email_delivery: (2 sp at beginning)
    delivery_method: :smtp (4 sp at beginning, 1 sp between the colons)
    smtp_settings: (4 sp)
      enable_startttls_auto: true (6 sp,1 sp after colon)
      address: "smtp.gmail.com" (6 sp,1 sp after colon)
      port: '587' (6 sp,1 sp after colon,single inverted commas)
      domain: "smtp.gmail.com" (6 sp, 1 sp after colon)
      authentication: plain  (6 sp, 1 sp after colon)
      user_name: "username@gmail.com" (6 sp,1 sp after colon)
      password: "1234"  (6 sp, 1 sp after colon)

Comment: put the code and any messages to your original question. these comments are not made for code :)